# Viewcontroller does not have member named

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I declared the variable outside of the scope, use the variable inside of viewdidload but I'm unable to access it after the load?

```
class SearchVC: UITableViewController {

var  userList:NSString = "";

override func viewDidLoad() {
userList = "blah"
}

//Can't access userlist here, "does not have member named userlist"
```

Comment: just create a method and access it there

Comment: I'm new to iOS swift, can you provide an example

Comment: func whatever() {   access it here } the same you did inside viewDidLoad

Comment: You have created the userList with uppercase L but the error message shows lower case. can you please check that

Comment: There's no way of access it without a function?  The variable is on top of the hierchy of the scope so I don't see why it cant access it without a function

Comment: Sorry but you can't You can access it inside viewDidLoad or any custom method

Comment: In my actual code the case sensitivity is identical, I just didn't uppercase L in my stackoverflow example above

Comment: @DevTonio I already knew it. Just move it inside viewDidLoad

Comment: unfortunately i need to access this variable after the load too

Comment: @DevTonio Just a note no need to use NSString. Swift native type is String. You can omit it there var  userList = ""

Comment: How can I create a variable that is accessible anywhere inside my view controller without having to use a function

Comment: @DevTonio Like I said you can't. Why do you need that?

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm pretty sure it is possible. As a matter of fact, I just ran the code provided by the OP, and it ran successfully. I'm not sure what the problem is here, but it seems as though it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put that in a function and call it in your view did load...

func userListString () {

var  userList:NSString = "";

}

then put it in your

viewDidLoad{

userListString()

}

Comment: did you figure it out? and how to call your function in multiple places?

Comment: Yes, I used a struct therefore I can now access it anywhere in the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I used a struct

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var users:NSArray!
}

  MyVariables.users = "whatever"
```